# Java.util.timer loops, program gets stuck (infinite loop?)

Tags: java, timer

I'm here to bring up yet another logical problem I'm having but can't resolve!

I've got this class right here:

```
package data;

import gui.GUIJuego;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import dominio.Adorno;
import dominio.EdificioNoPublico;
import dominio.EdificioPublico;
import dominio.Item;

public class Administrador {

private Ciudad ciudad;
private int contadorExplosion;
private boolean endofgame;
private Dificultad dificultad;
private Constructora constructora;

public Administrador(Ciudad ciudad, int contadorExplosion, boolean endofgame, Dificultad dificultad, Constructora constructora) {
    this.ciudad = ciudad;
    this.contadorExplosion = contadorExplosion;
    this.endofgame = endofgame;
    this.dificultad = dificultad;
    this.constructora = constructora;
}

public Administrador(){
    this.setCiudad(new Ciudad());
    this.setContadorExplosion(0);
    this.setEndofgame(false);
    this.setDificultad(new Dificultad(1));
    this.setConstructora(new Constructora());
}

public void administrar(final GUIJuego juego){

    Timer timer = new Timer("Juego");

    this.setEndofgame(false);

    while(endofgame == false){


        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
            public void run() {

                juego.getArcaLabel().setText("Arca: " + getCiudad().getArca());
                juego.getPuntosBellezaLabel().setText("Puntos de Belleza: " + getCiudad().getPuntosBelleza());
                juego.getHabitantesLabel().setText("Habitantes: " + getCiudad().getCantidadHabitantes() + " / " + getCiudad().getCantidadHabitantesDisponibles());
                getEgresosIngresos();
                tryExplotar();

            }

        }, 0, 1000);

    }

}

private void getEgresosIngresos(){

    for(Item i : this.getCiudad().getItems()){

        if(i.getContadorTiempo() == 89){

            i.setContadorTiempo(0);

            if(i instanceof EdificioNoPublico)
                this.getCiudad().setArca(this.getCiudad().getArca() + ((EdificioNoPublico) i).getRenta());
            else
                this.getCiudad().setArca(this.getCiudad().getArca() - getCostosAdornosEdificiosPublicos(i));

        } else { i.setContadorTiempo(i.getContadorTiempo() + 1); }
    }

}

private int getCostosAdornosEdificiosPublicos(Item i){

    if(i instanceof EdificioPublico)
        return ((EdificioPublico) i).getCostoMantenimiento();
    else if(i instanceof Adorno)
        return ((Adorno) i).getCostoMantenimiento();

    return 0;
}

private void tryExplotar(){

    if(this.getContadorExplosion() == 299 && this.getCiudad().getItems() != null){

        Random rnd = new Random();

        if(rnd.nextInt(100) < this.getCiudad().getProbabilidadExplosion() && this.getCiudad().getItems().size() > 0){
            this.getCiudad().getItems().remove( rnd.nextInt ( this.getCiudad().getItems().size() ) );
            this.setContadorExplosion(0);
        }

        rnd = null;

    }else{ this.setContadorExplosion(this.getContadorExplosion() + 1); }

}

// ### Getters y Setters ###

public Ciudad getCiudad() {
    return ciudad;
}

public void setCiudad(Ciudad ciudad) {
    this.ciudad = ciudad;
}

public int getContadorExplosion() {
    return contadorExplosion;
}

public void setContadorExplosion(int contadorExplosion) {
    this.contadorExplosion = contadorExplosion;
}

public boolean isEndofgame() {
    return endofgame;
}

public void setEndofgame(boolean endofgame) {
    this.endofgame = endofgame;
}


public Dificultad getDificultad() {
    return dificultad;
}

public void setDificultad(Dificultad dificultad) {
    this.dificultad = dificultad;
}

public Constructora getConstructora() {
    return constructora;
}

public void setConstructora(Constructora constructora) {
    this.constructora = constructora;
}

// ### Fin Getters y Setters ##
}
```

But what you guys would be interested in would be this particular method:

```
public void administrar(final GUIJuego juego){

    Timer timer = new Timer("Juego");

    this.setEndofgame(false);

    while(endofgame == false){


        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
            public void run() {

                juego.getArcaLabel().setText("Arca: " + getCiudad().getArca());
                juego.getPuntosBellezaLabel().setText("Puntos de Belleza: " + getCiudad().getPuntosBelleza());
                juego.getHabitantesLabel().setText("Habitantes: " + getCiudad().getCantidadHabitantes() + " / " + getCiudad().getCantidadHabitantesDisponibles());
                getEgresosIngresos();
                tryExplotar();

            }

        }, 0, 1000);

    }

}
```

Now, as far as I can see with the debugger, the timer is looping and I'm not entirely sure it's even trying to run the functions inside it, what I do know is that the frame (the parameter GUIJuego is a swing frame) works fine, but the timer's getting the program all stuck, am I making any logical errors, or thinking the timer wrong?

I'd like to thank you from beforehand for reading this.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling timer.scheduleAtFixedRate inside a busy while loop. You most likely only want to call it once.

When you use a TimerTask, the execution happens on another thread. I can't tell if you actually need another thread here, but if not, the simplest way to do what you're trying to do would be just

```
while(!endOfGame) {
   juego.getArcaLabel().setText("Arca: " + getCiudad().getArca());
   juego.getPuntosBellezaLabel().setText("Puntos de Belleza: " + getCiudad().getPuntosBelleza());
   juego.getHabitantesLabel().setText("Habitantes: " + getCiudad().getCantidadHabitantes() + " / " + getCiudad().getCantidadHabitantesDisponibles());
   getEgresosIngresos();
   tryExplotar();

  Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

If you do need to execute the timer in a separate thread, then you need to a better method for waiting for the timer thread to finish executing than the busy wait (while) loop. You could, for example, use thead.join(), but then you would have to explicitly create the timer thread, rather than relying on Timer internal logic. Or you can synchronize on an object and use wait/notify constructs to let the main thread know when to resume.

Comment: That worked, I can't believe I made such a mistake! Thank you so much, though!

The only issue is that I need a way to confirm that the game is paused so I can pause the timer as well, or whether the game has finished. But that has fixed the problem.